# What command line tool should I use to extract a string from a file using a complex regexp

Tags: regex

### Problem

In a linux script I want to assign several variables with data from a file.

The command should be able to:

- use complex regexp: meaning normal java/javascript/php/perl regexps,
  I can adapt to some variations
- return at stdout the first capturing group (or a capturing group specified by parameter). If it supports named capturing groups could receive the name as a parameter: `regextractor ""
- ideally should already exist in standard linux distributions maybe on osx as well

### Sample

I'm searching for a command like

```
mydate=`regextractor "^date:\s*(\S{10}).*$" myfile.md`
mytitle=`regextractor "^title:\s*(.*)\s*$" myfile.md`
echo $mydate - $mytitle
```

My file:

```
---
slug: article1
date: 2012-01-29 15:34:01
title: What is the best monetary system invented til now?
author: raisercostin<raisercostin@gmail.com>
tags: currency,monetary,system
type: question
toslug: article
```

The regexp was tested here: https://regex101.com/r/y311eP/1

### I tried

- UPDATE: grep - the default grep is using a simplified regex
   `grep -o "toslug:\(.*\)" myfile.md` => `toslug: article`
- UPDATE: grep extended - it supports complex regex but not capturing groups
    `grep --color=no -oE "toslug:(.*)" myfile.md` => `toslug: article`
- sed - it doesn't support capturing groups so a line is returned.
   `sed -nE "s/^date:\s*(\S*)//p" myfile.md`
   UPDATE: it actually supports capturing groups but you need to enable --regexp-extended with -E parameter
- awk - it doesn't support capturing groups so a line is returned
   `awk '/^date:\s*(.*)$/' myfile.md`

### UPDATE

- On my `Linux vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 3.13.0-101-generic #148-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 20 22:08:32 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`:

  - sed doesn't have the -E option documented but works for some cases
  - **WORKED** `sed -nE 's/^date:\s*(\S*)/\1/p' myfile.md` => `2012-01-29 15:34:01`
  - **DIDN'T WORK** `sed -nE 's/^date:\s*(\S{10})/\1/p' myfile.md` => `2012-01-29 15:34:01`
  - **DIDN'T WORK** `sed -nE 's/^date:\s*(\S*)$/\1/p' myfile.md` => no line
  - **WORKED** `awk '{ match($0, /^date:\s*(\S{10}).*$/, a); if(a[1])print a[1]}' myfile.md` => `2012-01-29`
- On my `Darwin costins-MBP.router1 16.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.3.0: Thu Nov 17 20:23:58 PST 2016; root:xnu-3789.31.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64`:

  - **PARTIALLY WORKED** `sed -nE 's/^date:\s*(\S*)/\1/p' myfile.md` => `2012-01-29 15:34:01` - the initial spaces are not consumed
  - **DIDN'T WORK** `sed -nE 's/^date:\s*(\S{10})/\1/p' myfile.md` => no line
  - **DIDN'T WORK** `sed -nE 's/^date:\s*(\S*)$/\1/p' myfile.md` => no line
  - **DIDN'T WORK** `awk '{ match($0, /^date:\s*(\S{10}).*$/, a); if(a[1])print a[1]}' myfile.md` => `awk: syntax error at source line 1{ match($0, >>>  /^date:\s*(\S{10}).*$/, <<<`

Comment: `sed` supports capture groups. Use `\1` in the replacement to get the match for the group.

Comment: You're right about the existence of \1 and it works only if -E is passed a parameter not documented in my ubuntu distribution. Anyway, it seems that there are other limitations: start/end of line and number of characters matched.

Comment: I've never needed to use `-E` for it.

Comment: `sed` uses BRE, so you need to use backslash before `(` to make a capture group.

Comment: If I'm removing that -E I get the following `sed -n 's/^date:\s*(\S*)$/\1/p' myfile.md
sed: -e expression #1, char 22: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS` . This is why I initially said that it doesn't support capturing groups.

Comment: `-E` makes it uses ERE, then you don't need the backslash.

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to use "standard" regexps :( . I know that are some variations between perl/java/php but there is a core that doesn't change. Escaping parenthesis is surprising for a developer. That is way I was asking about a solution where general regex works. Like in the link provided: https://regex101.com/r/y311eP/1 . I'm trying to find a solution that will work for majority of regexes without *nix specific historical **surprising** quircks

Comment: Practically every tool that supports regular expressions has a slightly different dialect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a perl oneliner:

```
perl -E 'undef$/;$_=<>;($d,$t)= $_ =~  /\ndate:\s*(\S{10}).+\ntitle:\s*(.+?)\R/s;say "$d - $t";' <file.txt
```

**Output:**

```
2012-01-29 - What is the best monetary system invented til now?
```

*file.txt*

```
---
slug: article1
date: 2012-01-29 15:34:01
title: What is the best monetary system invented til now?
author: raisercostin<raisercostin@gmail.com>
tags: currency,monetary,system
type: question
toslug: article
```

Comment: Thanks. It works on ubuntu with `perl -E 'undef$/;$_=<>;($d,$t)= $_ =~  /date:\s*(\S{10}).*$/s;say "[$d$t]";' <myfile.md` but doesnt if the regex starts with `^`  like in `perl -E 'undef$/;$_=<>;($d,$t)= $_ =~  /^date:\s*(\S{10}).*$/s;say "[$d$t]";' <myfile.md`. But at least the behavior is identical on ubuntu and osx.

Comment: It worked with the modifier m: `perl -E 'undef$/;$_=<>;($d,$t)= $_ =~ /^date:\s*(\S{10}).*$/m;say "[$d$t]";' <myfile.md` on both ubuntu and osx. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

(gnu) awk supports captures:

```
awk '/^date/ { match($0, /^date:[[:blank:]]*([^[:blank:]]{10}).*$/, a); print a[1]}' myfile.md
```

gives: `2012-01-29`

```
awk '/title/ { match($0, /^title:[[:blank:]]*([^[:blank:]]*.*$)/, a); print a[1]}' myfile.md
```

gives: `What is the best monetary system invented til now?`

Comment: Thanks. It worked perfectly with a variation that doesn't need the initial filtering done with `/^date/`. It worked with: `awk '{ match($0, /^date:\s*(\S{10}).*$/, a); if(a[1])print a[1]}' myfile.md` and `awk '{ match($0, /^title:\s*(.*).*$/, a); if(a[1])print a[1]}' myfile.md`

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work on osx `Darwin costins-MBP.router1 16.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.3.0: Thu Nov 17 20:23:58 PST 2016; root:xnu-3789.31.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64` . I get the `awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
 /title/ { match($0, >>>  /^title:[[:blank:]]*([^[:blank:]]*.*$)/, <<<
` error

Comment: To avoid problems with sed/awk variants, you can easily do with ruby: `ruby -ne 'puts $1 if /^date:\s*(\S{10}).*$/' myfile.md` and `ruby -ne 'puts $1 if /^title:\s*(\S*.*$)/' myfile.md`

Answer (score 0):

Based on Jan Smydke response. This matches two groups.

**Input:**

```
regextractor () {
    perl -E 'undef$/;$_=<>;($v1,$v2)= $_ =~ /'$1'/m;say "$v1$v2";' <$2
}
regextractor "^date:\s*(\S{10}).*$" myfile.md
regextractor "^title:\s*(.*)\s*$" myfile.md
```

**Output:**

```
2012-01-29
What is the best monetary system invented til now?
```